# .Net core api returns 404 while saving large file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have .net core api which saves file on a file server. It works fine when file sizes are small such as 10 kb , 1 Mb, 10 Mb. However when I try to save file of 100 mb, It returns :

404 - File or directory not found.
  The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I have updated kestrel options to ignore file size:

```
 .UseKestrel(options => {
                options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;

            })
```

File saving code:

```
using (var imageFile = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                imageFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                imageFile.Flush();
            }
```

Web config:

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

However it still does not work(for large file size) when hosted on server .
Though it works fine when I host in my local machine using iis express.

What could be the possible reason? Or Any settings I am missing here?

Comment: how long does it take to load that file? or how long does it take to get 404?

Comment: @ Simonare: It happens instantly .

Comment: @Gautam you should "Upload files with Streaming" per MS documentation.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2#uploading-large-files-with-streaming

Comment: This is how I am doing it now:   using (var imageFile = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    imageFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    imageFile.Flush();
                }

Answer (score 1):

please check [Unexpected Not Found error with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2#unexpected-not-found-error-with-iis). You need to increase/set `maxAllowedContentLength`

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <!-- This will handle requests up to 50MB -->
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I have them already like this:
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>